# Is it possible to mix number of Columns in GridView

Tags: android, xml, gridview

Is there a way to mix the number of columns in a gridView? For example, can I create a gridView such as...

```
    X   X   X   X   X <--generally how most columns will be arranged
      X   X   X   X   <--this is the row that is in question
        X   X   X     <--I know this is possible by hiding views, columns are aligned
    X   X   X   X   X
            .
            .
            .
```

If you look at the second row, not only is there one less column (maybe the view inside of that column is hidden) but it is also centered. That is the part I am unsure about. I know I can hide views, but how can I hide + center a row while using a gridView?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why are you attached to the idea of using a gridview? Are you displaying a checkered pattern? A listview is a more suitable for this type of layout.

Comment: ListView is not a valid solution. This is not personal preference, I am just inquiring about the abilities of gridView. I think that the answer is this is not possible. I have tried a number of things, including hiding the column and the items did not re-arrange to center themselves.

Comment: Correct, a grid won't support that behavior. Even with flexible grid or table widgets you end up with a jagged effect where there are a varying number of columns per row, but the rows never change their cell alignment. What you are trying to do violates the idea of a grid. However, Etsy has published AndroidStaggeredGrid which OOTB is similar to what you are trying to do, only it's staggered vertically.

Comment: Your response to my response I will accept as correct answer. I agree that this is not possible after a lot of research. Thank you!